# pl/sql 12C - MERGE INTO output error Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be update IU.LOGIN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't understand my problem in pl/sql 12c with the following code:

```sql
MERGE INTO ident_utilisateur iu
USING users us
ON ((regexp_substr (iu.LOGIN, '[^_]+', 1)) = TO_CHAR(us.cnbf))
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE
SET
iu.login = (regexp_substr (iu.login, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.email_contact = (regexp_substr (iu.email_contact, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.valide = 1,
iu.date_fin = ''
WHERE iu.login LIKE '%_LOG_%' 
AND iu.login NOT LIKE '%AUT_LOG%'
```

(iu.LOGIN actually looks like "169_LOG_04/10/2022", the regex output "169" AND
us.cnbf looks like "169"
)

this code expected
`error Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be update IU.LOGIN`

For info:
this code work but it don't JOIN the users' table

```sql
update ident_utilisateur iu
set
iu.login = (regexp_substr (iu.login, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.email_contact = (regexp_substr (iu.email_contact, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.valide = 1,
iu.date_fin = ''
--FROM ident_utilisateur iu
--INNER JOIN users us ON (regexp_substr (iu.login, '[^_]+', 1)) = TO_CHAR(us.CNBF)
WHERE iu.login LIKE '%_LOG_%'
AND iu.login NOT LIKE '%AUT_LOG%'
```

if i uncomment the From and INNER line it output `SQL command not properly ended`

Really thanks for ur helps!

Thery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update ident_utilisateur iu
set
iu.login = (regexp_substr (iu.login, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.email_contact = (regexp_substr (iu.email_contact, '[^_]+', 1)),
iu.valide = 1,
iu.date_fin = ''
WHERE iu.login LIKE '%_LOG_%'
AND iu.login NOT LIKE '%AUT_LOG%'
AND exists (select null from users us where regexp_substr (iu.login, '[^_]+', 1) = TO_CHAR(us.CNBF))
```

Comment: it seems to be ok.. ! thank u very much..!  Thery